# SQL Correlated Subquery - help required with MAX

Tags: php, mysql, correlated-subquery

I have two tables, 'backorders' and 'sku'

**sku**

```
id | orderdate | sku | expectedship
```

**backorders**

```
orderdate | ordernum | saleschannel | sku | expectedship
```

In the sku table, is a list of items that have different expected ship dates based on the date of order.

E.g.

```
1  | Apple  |  01.08.2014  |  19.10.2014
2  | Apple  |  02.08.2014  |  28.10.2014
3  | Pear   |  02.08.2014  |  20.10.2014
4  | Grape  |  02.08.2014  |  22.10.2014
```

In the backorders table, is a list of items that have been ordered.  The Ordernum is the unique reference where multiple items can be ordered.

E.g.

```
02.08.2014  |  order1  |  a  |  apple
02.08.2014  |  order1  |  a  |  grape
02.08.2014  |  order1  |  a  |  pear
03.08.2014  |  order2  |  c  |  banana
```

What I am trying to achieve is for each backorder, populate the max expected ship date across all items for that order.  
E.g.

```
02.08.2014  |  order1  |  a  |  apple  |  28.10.2014
02.08.2014  |  order1  |  a  |  grape  |  28.10.2014
02.08.2014  |  order1  |  a  |  pear   |  28.10.2014
03.08.2014  |  order2  |  c  |  banana |  NULL
```

As you can see above, is order1 shows the maximum/oldest date for all 3 sku's ordered. 
The below query shows me the expected ship date for each sku; however cannot work out how to get the max date per order number.

```
SELECT
    backorders.orderdate,
    backorders.ordernum,
    backorders.saleschannel,
    backorders.sku,
    setup.expectedship
FROM backorders
LEFT OUTER JOIN setup ON backorders.orderdate = setup.orderdate AND backorders.sku =     setup.sku
WHERE (backorders.saleschannel = 'a') 
   OR (backorders.saleschannel ='b') 
   OR (backorders.saleschannel ='c') 
ORDER BY backorders.ordernum DESC
```

I can also separately manage to identify the max date for each ordernum:

```
SELECT
    backorders.ordernum,
    MAX(setup.expectedship) AS `MAX(expectedship)`
FROM backorders
INNER JOIN setup ON backorders.sku = setup.sku AND backorders.orderdate = setup.orderdate
WHERE (setup.orderdate = backorders.orderdate) 
  AND (setup.sku = backorders.sku) 
  AND (backorders.saleschannel = 'a') 
  OR  (backorders.saleschannel ='b') 
  OR  (backorders.saleschannel ='c')
GROUP BY backorders.ordernum
```

Is there a way I can run the first query to identify the expected ship per order line, and then a subquery to update the expected ship across all ordernum to maximum?

Comment: cant you just left join the two queries together?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've attempted to join the two queries; however not with any success

Comment: could you provide a sqlfiddle with the tables setup? I think I know a better way to do it but can't replicate without the setup

Comment: I hope those things that look dates aren't really dates.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've never seen sqlfiddle, but will see what I can do

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, they are dates..?

Comment: @troy all you have to do is go to sqlfiddle.com and then create your table and insert the data then the queries can be run from there. its a very helpful website

Comment: also dates in mysql are formatted `2014-03-03`, datetime is formatted `2014-03-03 00:00:00`

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you.  Just adding the tables and example data now.  Re: the dates.  I know, the fields are set to date, I've just written them down above poorly.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that they are in the right format :) i was thinking you were going to have a bit of work on your hands to fix it all lol

Comment: your column count is off on the backorders table as well.. what are the expectedship dates for the backorders table?

Comment: @troy see my edit.. I posted a working solution as well as a sqlfiddle showing the desired result.

Comment: Sounds like a typical application for [MySQL docs: 3.6.4 The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee004/22 @JohnRuddell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to what I was referring in my comment you could just join the two queries together... i would try to replicate this to ensure it works.. but your date formats are off and I don't have the time to format them all.

```
SELECT
    t.orderdate,    t.ordernum,
    t.saleschannel, t.sku,
    t1.expectedship
FROM
(   SELECT
        b.orderdate,    b.ordernum,
        b.saleschannel, b.sku,
        s.expectedship
    FROM backorders b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN setup s ON b.orderdate = s.orderdate AND b.sku = s.sku
    WHERE b.saleschannel IN('a', 'b', 'c')
    ORDER BY b.ordernum DESC
)t
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT
        b.ordernum,
        MAX(s.expectedship) AS expectedship
    FROM backorders b
    INNER JOIN setup s ON b.sku = s.sku AND b.orderdate = s.orderdate
    WHERE (s.sku = b.sku) 
      AND b.saleschannel IN('a', 'b', 'c')
    GROUP BY b.ordernum
)t1 on t1.ordernum = t.ordernum
order by ordernum;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7782/1)

Comment: With a few changes (mostly due to my poor details), the first query is absolutely what I need.  @JohnRuddel thank you so much.

Comment: @troy sure thing! now for some recommendations... your where clause is WAYYYYY too clutered.. notice in my answer i changed it to IN('a', 'b', 'c')... does the exact same thing but is much easier to read and is easier to maintain. another recommendation.. add aliases to your tables.. notice i call backorders b and then call b.orderdate.. easier to read and is the general accepted way to write queries :) i'll edit your fiddle to incorporate these things.. good luck! don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: @troy also you INNER JOIN setup for the MAX date query.. ON orderdate.. so you dont need that in your WHERE because you already filter it

Comment: @troy here is the sqlfiddle with your query cleaned up. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee004/24 hope thats helpful :)

Comment: Thank you again.  You've saved me hours of hair pulling. :)

Comment: @troy the pleasure is mine :)